# dropdown menu in IE7,8 needs fixin'

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I've had lots of success in getting IE to play nice in the past, but I'm buffaloed here.  The dropdown menu is visible and works, but it's having some margin/padding issues and no matter what kind of conditional statement or hack I try to employ, it won't straighten out.

Example page: [www.erisdesigns.net](http://www.erisdesigns.net)

HTML (links removed so that I can post):

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <ul id="nav">
    <dl class="dropdown">
      <dt id="one-ddheader" onmouseover="ddMenu('one',1)" onmouseout="ddMenu('one',-1)"></dt>
      <dd id="one-ddcontent" onmouseover="cancelHide('one')" onmouseout="ddMenu('one',-1)">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="dropdown">
     <dt id="two-ddheader" onmouseover="ddMenu('two',1)" onmouseout="ddMenu('two',-1)"></dt>
      <dd id="two-ddcontent" onmouseover="cancelHide('two')" onmouseout="ddMenu('two',-1)">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
   </dl>         
  </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    top:80px;
    width:65%;
    margin-left:600px;
    padding:0;
    background:#999;
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}

.dropdown {float:left; text-align:center; font-size:14px; padding-right:5px; color:#FFF;}
.dropdown dt {width:175px; padding:8px; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; background:transparent;}
.dropdown dt:hover {background:transparent; color:#000;}
.dropdown dd {position:absolute; width:175px; display:none; background:transparent; z-index:200; opacity:0;}
.dropdown ul {width:175px; margin-top:23px; list-style:none;}
.dropdown li {display:inline-block; margin-left:-108px; float:left; padding-left:35px; text-align:left;}
.dropdown a, .dropdown a:active, .dropdown a:visited {display:inline-block; padding:5px 0px 10px 15px; color:#CCC; text-decoration:none; background:#999; width:175px; float:left;}
.dropdown a:hover {background:#999; color:#000;}
.dropdown a.menu {background:transparent; width:200px; float:left; text-align:left; color:#FFF;}
.dropdown a.menu:hover {color:#000}
```

Comment: Can you show us the JavaScript you're using? Or, rather, an example page somewhere online?

Comment: silly me...www.erisdesigns.net

Comment: Wow, many hacks there… Why are you testing `if ( -1 != navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") )` *inside* a conditional comment? And what if this code was outside that block and someone spoofs the User Agent string (very easy in Opera and WebKit-based browsers)? BTW, you should make your email address clickable; it's already there in plain text, so the bad guys can easily scrape it.

Comment: Thanks Marcel...I'm obviously not much of a coder...so, eliminated unnecessary hacks might solve the IE issue?

Comment: It's a horrible mess in IE 6. :-P

Comment: Perhaps it helps if you fix these: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.erisdesigns.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imo too much markup. Try replacing `<ul id="nav">` with `<div id="nav">` since you are not wrapping anything with `<li></li>` so IE might have some problem with that.

Comment: I am wrapping - I just excluded the links because I don't have enough clout yet to post more than one..:)

Comment: thank-you GaVra, total helped.  still having some java issues with IE, but on the right track.